# [name deleted] spamming for the same link farm link in every answer

Tags: discussion, spam

Just noticed this user [name deleted] is spamming StackOverflow entries with the same link-farm hyperlink over and over.

What is the process of getting them removed/banned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I report a specific bad user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66444/how-can-i-report-a-specific-bad-user)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks -- in the future just flag the content, or if it's particularly egregious / urgent, email us via the link provided at the bottom of every page.

Comment: I was looking for a flag, must be suffering code-blindness. I see it now very clearly :) I noticed that any down-vote points are lost after user deletion... the flag is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @HiTech Magic: The "lost rep" will return after a rep recalc, your "real" rep is shown at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation