# Feature request: Flag Profile

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page

Originally posted at [Pro Webmasters Meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/option-to-report-a-profile) - can we get a "Flag Profile" option to purge the inevitable [Buy Femara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215699/femara-to-buy)'s and [Sildenafil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311763/sildenafil)'s of the StackExchange community?

Comment: See also [How can I report a specific bad user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66444/how-can-i-report-a-specific-bad-user)