# Am I allowed to request comment noise cleanup on a per-user basis?

Tags: discussion, comments

While following an "interesting" question on Stack Overflow, I had a look at the asker of that question and found that his activity tab was filled with short and meaningless comments.

The user has an extremely high comment-noise level; `Thanks` and `good example` seem to be a very common comment which repeat on nearly every answer he receives on his questions. While I know that we should tell people to stop that and use the voting mechanism instead, I wondered if I'm allowed to flag that user and request a major cleanup of all his comments.

And yes, I'm aware that's a pretty rare and tiny problem on SO, but I'm wondering if we should lay that into the hands of a Moderator, educate the user or leave him be.

**Edit:** I didn't mean a complete deletion of all the users comments, but instead a manual cleanup done by a Moderator. The main intention was to not clutter up the comment-flag-queue with dozens and dozens of flags for those comments.

Comment: For what it's worth, a mod has asked that people [not call out bad users by name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66444/131713). Yes, I know this will lead to "well, can you show us an example?" comments in many cases. Just wanted to point it out; I had forgotten, myself.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Hadn't heard about that, good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Pekka LOL, I signed up just to upvote

Comment: @Michael thx man!

Comment: I came here to say this!

Comment: good example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Edit:**
> Tim Post ♦ confirms:
>
> It's MUCH easier for us to just deal with individual flags. @PaddedCell Just flag appropriately in a way that won't leave broken remnants of a conversation. It's much faster for us to go through them that way rather than digging through a user's entire timeline. Each individual flag we receive is ideally actionable with a few (or single) click.
>
> and Robert Harvey ♦ adds:
>
> Except when an entire conversation on a post needs to be purged. If you want that, a single flag on the post will suffice.

Old answer:

> Am I allowed to request comment noise cleanup on a user-base?

I'm against this - be it noise or not, a comment can be part of a meaningful conversation that would be rendered useless without it.

For example:

> Hi Jon.Could you provide an example.what if i set it to public
>
> Thomas,Could you review your example.Since i think the String phone in first code snippet should be public.!!!!

etc.

I'm not saying these are great contributions, but you can't simply do a `delete from comments where user = #`. They need individual flagging IMO.

Comment: I didn't mean a complete clean-up, for sure not. My intention was not to clutter up the comment-flag-queue but instead just issue one Moderator-Flag. Manual cleanup is of course still necessary.

Comment: @Padded ah, I see. I guess that depends on what is easier for the mods to deal with. I'll leave this in place and delete later when a mod has answered

Comment: It's MUCH easier for us to just deal with individual flags. @PaddedCell Just flag appropriately in a way that won't leave broken remnants of a conversation. It's much faster for us to go through them that way rather than digging through a user's entire timeline. Each individual flag we receive is ideally actionable with a few (or single) click.

Comment: Except when an entire conversation on a post needs to be purged.  If you want that, a single flag on the post will suffice.