# How can I report abuse of the edit privilege?

Tags: support, edits, moderation

In the case of objectionable questions, answers, and comments, I'd flag the behavior, as recommended here: [How can I report a specific bad user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66444/how-can-i-report-a-specific-bad-user) However, there is no way to flag edits. So how can I report abuse of the edit privilege?

I ask because I recently encountered a user who made many edits not in accordance with the [guidelines for the edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: just flag the post that has been abused by edit (using "Other" kind of flag) and explain the issue in the flag message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. If the user really damaged the post, and if you have the edit privilege, then first rollback the question/answer to undo the damage.
2. Flag the post with a custom moderator flag like this:

   > User *[user name or user id here]* has damaged the post with his edit, and he has done more edits like this.