# Previously banned user up to something suspicious *shifty eyes*

Tags: support, ban

This user https://stackoverflow.com/users/4677723/sissy-girl is the same user that was banned here a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950000/guys-hello-i-need-to-check-my-code-cause-i-dont-know-whats-wrong-can-anyone-h

If you visit the blog linked from their profile (http://gibberishstack.blogspot.com.br/search?updated-min=2015-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&updated-max=2016-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&max-results=8) you can see they are a serial SO troll.

They have answered a number of old questions in the last few minutes. All of which have been instantly upvoted. I suspect by the same user with a second account.

Not sure what they are up but maybe worth somebody with a ban hammer keeping an eye out. ๏_๏

Comment: You should be flagging their content if someone is doing something inappropriate, not posting on meta.

Comment: They haven't actually done anything flaggable yet since re-creating the account. I decided to post here after reading this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66445/180262 where posting here was suggested. As far as I can see there isn't any other way of reporting something like this

Comment: The 2 member names seem to be gone

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn You don't think that creating accounts to subvert a ban or voting fraud is "anything flaggable"?  If you suspect either of those things it most certainly merits a flag.  It's also something that should be handled in private between you and the mods, not out in public.

Comment: @Servy I think that the 'new version' of the member hadn't posted yet.

Comment: They had posted but what they posted seemed legitimate. Ok @servy you are right. I think it would make sense though to have a "flag this user" link on the user account page too as this is what I wanted to do, rather than flag a specific post

Comment: @SabreTooth If they hadn't then there wouldn't be any problems to flag.  The problem is that, "They have answered a number of old questions in the last few minutes. All of which have been instantly upvoted. I suspect by the same user with a second account." So yes, the second account had been posting.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn If they're subverting a suspension and committing voting fraud then those are things that merit reporting.  You simply need to make it clear in your flag what you feel the problem is.

Comment: @Servy fair enough! (still waiting for my coffee to kick in)

Answer (score 38):

Yeah, it's a troll. They've been targeting me for the last few weeks with code snippets that draw dicks (which amazingly few people even noticed), suggested edits [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7284242), and user accounts named Brad Larson that completely copy my profile. It's been moderately entertaining to destroy my own accounts.

It's also been a great opportunity to find inattentive reviewers to ban, I'll tell you that.

If you see other accounts like this, flag them and we'll feed them into the anti-troll system. That should hopefully block them after a while.

Comment: LOL, that code snippet is just priceless! :D

Comment: wow, can you believe someone accepted such a large suggested edit

Comment: I noticed but the code snippet made me laugh. Looks like you've got a little fan club forming Brad.

Comment: The endgame here is to someday trick you into deleting your own account, I just know it.

Comment: Lul, they are still [suggesting such edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7560976), not on your posts though :D

Comment: @nicael - And someone just earned themselves a review ban.