# How can we request a question to be [featured] in Meta Stack Exchange and per-site metas?

Tags: discussion, support, featured-tag

What is the appropriate way for a normal user (without diamond moderator privilege) to request a question to be featured in Meta Stack Exchange and per-site metas?

- If the OP of the post is a staff member, should one post a comment in the question requesting the OP to feature the question? or...
- If the OP of the post is a staff member, should one post an answer to the question requesting the OP to feature the question? Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375826 (deleted answer)

  [image] or...
- Should a new question be posted requesting the question to be featured? Examples:

  - [Add the [featured] tag to the "Updates to Privacy Policy (September 2021)" post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370707)
  - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375832 ([deleted question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veizh.png)) or...
- Should the question which needs to be featured be flagged as *in need of moderator intervention* explaining the reason for why the post should be featured? (Also, who will handle these kinda flags? Staff or mods?)
- Should one request a moderator or staff in chat to feature the post?

---

What should be done if the post needs to be featured immediately (in case of time-sensitive posts)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are mods declining flags to add \[featured\] to pertinent questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333273/why-are-mods-declining-flags-to-add-featured-to-pertinent-questions)

Comment: @RobertLongson Nah. That post talks about why mods are declining the requests, whereas this post is asking about what is the appropriate way to request the post to be featured.

Comment: It answers the question. Here, you can't, on site metas, flag the post.

Comment: @RobertLongson https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9119565#9119565

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator for MSO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules which Meta Stack Exchange moderators need to follow regarding the \[featured\] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370909/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343533/282094 - On MSE our CMs must make the decision, because the post shows up on every site, on per-site-metas the moderator can add the tag since it only highlights the post on that one site.

Comment: @Rob Nope. [That question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370909) is regarding moderators, my question is regarding how normal users can request the post to be featured.

Comment: @Rob , there's nothing about _**how**_ a normal user can request a post to be featured in the post which you linked. It just talks about rules which mods need to follow before featuring a post based on their judgement.

Comment: For the record, I agree this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should simply write a comment beneath the question to say something like:

> I think this question should be tagged as featured because …

I think that this should be done on only rare occasions when a question worthy of being featured was overlooked initially.

I think you should suggest rather than request a question be featured. Votes on your comment should keep it near the top of the comments and votes on the question should indicate to staff/moderators whether the question seems useful.

All other mechanisms you suggest are likely to interrupt the flow of Q&A (with moderation) far more.

Comment: Did you go through the comments of this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375832?

Comment: @RandomPerson I did, but only just now, and I don't think they are relevant to my comment.

Comment: PolyGeo, while you suggested me to comment, Tinkeringbell suggested me to flag. So I am not sure which method is more appropriate.

Comment: @RandomPerson Neither answer here suggests flagging.

Answer (score 3):

> What should be done if the post needs to be featured immediately (in case of time-sensitive posts)?

Practically - while it's a 2 second job, generally we trust the staff to manage it - and intervene with these tags as little as possible. In general - we hope folks do too, and not back seat drive policy with respect to that. That's to say, to a significant extent, staff should know, and when they don't, learn from their peers, what needs featuring, with only the occasional nudge from us.

As such - the first, clearest point of contact might be to comment that it would be helpful to feature network wide, and why.  I think in *general* [my answer here holds true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333276/135565), though admittedly - there's exceptional situations where mods may choose to add feature-tags where we feel staff are unable to and there's certain conditions met. That generally means the company actively doing things badly - and I think the current crop of folks seem to make it unlikely that a mod will have to make those decisions in a vacuum.

In addition chances are if there's a post of merit that needs to be featured, we'd let a CM know to pass on to other staff, ping a suitable point of contact if one is available - so dropping a link where we can see it and discussing it might be another approach - and most of us are regular on the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Journeyman Geek! Your answer mostly focuses on the last part of my post (*time-sensitive*). Would you like to answer any of the preceding questions?

Comment: Ah I felt that saying we usually trust stuff to handle it and giving them a heads-up over comments seems sufficient. Not sure what else needs adding there

Comment: "stuff"? Did you mean "staff"?

Comment: Yes I did. I blame using my phone, and autocucumber :D