# Why was a chatroom frozen after a remark was made about Australia?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation, frozen-rooms

This is the chatroom:

The [Garden of Eden](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112109/garden-of-eden)

This is the chat message:

[...have you seen the latest heresy video posted by Veritasium on YouTube? To think he's supposed have a PhD in physics education really makes me wonder about the education faculty in Australia; but then again, Norman Wildberger is from there also.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56022755#56022755)

Why did it cause a moderator to freeze the room?

Comment: Note the time stamps. There were more than two weeks between the two events.

Comment: Just don't offend the Aussies ...

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289913/369802: You don't get to call out people by name. Focus on the behavior, not the user or moderator. Also, given how you've already asked this on Skeptics (main, not meta though), I'm going to close this as site specific. Move your question to their meta and you'll likely get an answer there.

Comment: You already got an answer in the Skeptics main chat room, asking in three places at once isn't very efficient.

Comment: @rene how can I do that?  I am English, and so have a lifetime of training in offending Oz:)

Comment: For those interested, the explanation is given by the mod who froze the room. Start reading [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56179221#56179221).

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard Thanks!  Think I'll add that into my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Over fifteen days passed between the freezing of the room and the making of that remark, so I don't think that's the reason.  I also very much doubt that making such a remark would've been reason enough to freeze the room.

[Per John Dvorak](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8628307#8628307), the room was already getting close to being autofrozen, possibly due to inactivity.

---

**UPDATE**:

[Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56179221#56179221), down to the starred message, is the reason why that chat room was frozen, from the moderator who froze the room.