# I just saw a spam/bot/advertisement profile. Where can I find a button to require moderator attention?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, flags, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

There is no "flag" link in user profiles which can contain links and summary written clearly to advertise.

Example from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/users/70295/alecdorthy7).

> Looking for fast cash? Debit card
>   loans quick brings simple solution for
>   all your swift cash needs without any
>   credit check process.

There is also an URL but I will not make advertisement for them.

What about adding a "flag" link in profile next to website entry and the summary (about me) in the profile pages?

Answer (score 1):

Posting here is fine; as BalusC comments you can also flag one of their posts for moderator attention. If (like in this case, except for an already deleted spam post) there are no posts, you can also flag *any* post for moderator attention, explain the situation, and include a link to the user profile in the message.

I've taken care of this particular user. Thanks!

As for the feature request part of your question, that has been declined before: [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

Also note that advertisement in your "about me" field isn't per se forbidden – you're free to put in there pretty much whatever you want. Of course, if the whole purpose of the account is spamming, this rule doesn't hold, and clearly this was the case here.

Comment: It had a post, that was delete quite rapidly, but the profile hanged around. In such case, the flag link is still useful.