# Dealing with abusive user?

Tags: support, down-votes, abuse

I recently noticed (and [reported in meta.japanese.stackexchange.com](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/serial-downvoting-and-downvoting-etiquette-in-general)) a pattern of systematic downvoting by one user against all my questions and answers.

I have honestly no idea what the user's reasons or motivations are, since we have not interacted at all, barely even crossed path on the site (both answered the same question once), but he is clearly targeting me, not my content (which there is no physical way he could have read entirely during his downvoting sprees). He has not left a single comment on any post to justify his downvotes, nor has he replied to my polite requests to explain himself and/or stop this.

His first wave of downvotes was automatically reversed by the system **yesterday**, and I would have left it at that... But he has been at it again **today**, and just seems to have no other activity than downvoting my every contributions, which is getting a bit old, to be honest. This really isn't about the reputation points (which get returned each time by the system anyway), but I think a verbal notice enjoining him to play nicer with the community could go some way...

Because this particular form of abuse only has to do with votes, not post content, I don't think there is any way to flag him within the site (?). Also, because [our site](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) is still pretty young, it appears we do not have any moderators yet (*pro tempore* or otherwise)... Would any meta-SO moderators mind taking a look at it?

**Edit**: somehow missed [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/serial-downvotes-in-quick-succession-on-all-my-posts) when posting mine. Though I do not know what the policy for redundancy is, with support-requests... Please if necessary, feel free to close this question and I'll happily repost over there.

Comment: The dev team will check your meta, so raising your concerns there is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could always flag one of the posts that have been downvoted and add a note asking a moderator to have a look at it.

Some related reading

[Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

Comment: Thanks: just saw that too. Will do then! (but since the abusive part is in the pattern of repetition, I figured someone having a look at the whole series might be better).

Comment: @Dave, the moderators and the team have access to more information than you or I, so if your note states that you feel there's a pattern to the voting, they'll be able to look into that, so flagging one post should be sufficient =)