# Can we flag entire user accounts?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

Ok, so I got a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440837/mysql-convert-latin1-data-to-utf8/8556016#8556016) to an old question of mine.  Then answer didn't make any sense, and didn't look like it had anything to do with the question.  The [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105072/corporate-gifts) had no rep, and is called "corporate gifts" and the website of this user is a really spammy site. I flagged the question, however, when things like this happen, it would be very useful to flag the entire user, so that the user, and any users that appear to be the same, possibly created from the same IP address, or linking to the same URL can be investigated, and probably removed.

Comment: That guy *is* spam.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the canonical answer to this is that the question/answer flagging mechanism works good enough for this purpose and to just flag one of the user's answers and explain the situation to the mods (as you have done).

Comment: Yes, however, I believe that there may be more to look into.  The account only has 1 answer, so there may be more accounts being created for the same site, possibly on other sites within the stack exchange network.  I'm not sure what real-time data searching powers moderators have to determine if this user is being a real problem, or if this is just a one time thing from this site, and deleting the answer is enough.

Comment: @Kibbee Agreed; but if you note that in your flag, the mods can look into that.