# Should we have a way to flag a user?

Tags: support, flags, user-accounts

I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1323/133368) and its answer(s), but [sehe found a case](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4584879#4584879) where a user who has not posted any questions, answers, or comments needs to be flagged:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/486089/user486089

Comment: But they just want us to be aware of the dangers of herpes!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No they just want cheap SEO and pagerank. This is also known as link SPAM

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: But it was on http://stackoverflow.com, not http://health.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @sehe (It was a joke, guys.)

Comment: But there's no link in their profile :P. Their website link didn't get linked, I think it's because they're low rep

Comment: I'd love for a way to mark certain users as "problematic" but only to me. E.g. when I load a question that happens to be asked by someone I had a negative experience with in the past, for me only, their user card shows up differently (skull & crossbones overlay, bright yellow, whatever). I know we're supposed to judge questions alone, but I have a shortlist of users that I've had repeated bad experiences with and I'd rather just avoid them altogether. Sadly on several occasions I have answered the question before realizing who it was, and this the cycle continues...

Comment: @AaronBertrand What we need is an equivalent of the [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/) for Stack Exchange sites, that lets you tag users based on their user ids (so it works even when they change display names).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That profile seems harmless.  Because the user hasn't contributed any content, the SEO value (and the overall visibility) of his profile is practically zero.

Historically, unless the profile is especially harmful or abusive, we generally let people put [whatever they want in there.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog)  The one thing that we are a bit strict on is user names and Gravatars, since they are far more visible; they show up everywhere that a user posts a question or answer.

All that said, the user visited one day and never came back, so I doubt that the profile will be missed.  Unless there are objections (i.e. historical reasons), I'll go ahead and delete the account.

This particular scenario is an extremely rare edge case; reporting it on Meta seems to have served the purpose adequately.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Good information to know. And yeah, obviously, green light

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Robert! So we are expected to report stuff on meta that we can't flag? Fine with me.