# Dealing with downvote trolling

Tags: feature-request, flags, down-votes, trolling

In the past few days, somebody has been randomly downvoting several of my questions.

I know SO has an automated script that detects this kind of actions using a threshold, but sometimes trolls have too much time in their hands.

I'd like to propose a way to deal with this (and, potentially, other threats): a new kind of flag that applies to a **user account** instead of a post. In this case, a "mass downvote" flag.

Moderators could then look at a list of downvoted questions along with a (anonymized?) list of voting users to determine if the target account is the victim of trolling, enabling them to reverse the votes and/or take disciplinary action.

...Of course I'm open to other, completely different solutions.

Comment: So there is a problem with the automated script? Did it not catch something which you think it should have?

Comment: Flag your own post --> Other --> "I think I fell victom to serial downvotes and the automated script did not catch it. Can you please take a look?".

Comment: See also this: [Flag abusive users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users).  Flagging users has been asked and declined in the past.  Bill the Wizard has the right idea, flag a post and explain to the mods why you think that user is downvoting you.  They have *some* tools to work with regarding voting patterns

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you should probably include more information than that in order for the flag to be most helpful to moderators (who you think it is, why you think they're doing it, etc).

Comment: Without saying more, we have means of determining if someone is targeting you over a long period of time and who that might be, so there's no need for your suggested improvements. As Bill said, just raise a custom flag about what you suspect is going on and we'll look into it. In this case, I've warned the user who looks to be responsible and I'll see about getting the votes invalidated.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess that's the way to go

Comment: @BradLarson thanks for looking into it. I hadn't used post flags a lot in the past, so I incorrectly assumed they wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: Oh, great, now I have **legit** downvotes in Meta because of this question... :-)

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon - The "other" flags are pretty flexible in what they let you send our way. The more information you can provide, the more likely we are to see what might be going on, but we do look into all of those. Don't worry about the downvotes here, people are probably just disagreeing with the need for a new flag for this.

Answer (score 5):

> I know SO has an automated script that detects this kind of actions using a threshold, but sometimes trolls have too much time in their hands.

They don't have as much time on their hands as an automated script, which is one of the reasons why this issue is dealt with automatically.  The other is that flags against a **user account** really wouldn't give moderators the information they need.  If you suspect you've been downvoted by a particular user, flag the thing that makes you suspicious of that user (a comment they made to that effect for example).

Comment: I think he is referring to a series of downvotes (three two days ago, two today) that seem to be staying under the radar

Comment: A true troll would have made automated script for this as well