# What can I do against users who encourage bad behavior?

Tags: support

There are users on a particular SE site I go to that encourage bad behavior, for example, encouraging others to upvote a extremely poor answer (which has remained at 0, ironically), copying content from other sites as well as falsely accusing other users of breaking the rules (too common, from what I can tell of the user).

What can I do? Flag the user? Report to a moderator?

Comment: When I see a user 'misbehaving', I may let a mod know about it in the site chat room. Usually, they are aware and have been keeping tabs on the user. How was this user encouraging upvotes on the answer? Was this user the author?

Comment: "Wow this answer is really funny XD everyone +1!!!! If you don't u haf no life lol!" something along those lines, not verbatim

Comment: Oh, wrong link. I meant to use http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users.

Comment: Because this user is being abusive of his privs, and needs to be reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag the user for moderator attention, under Flag > Other and explain the situation. It might also be worth mentioning in the site's chat room(s) depending on traffic.