# Is it okay to use Emojis in your user profile's location field?

Tags: discussion, support, location, emoji

Is it permissible to use Emojis in the field for your location like I do now, or is this not? If it is not permissible, should we have an error message to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not offensive, it's not rude, it's not even spam, so it's not directly forbidden or against any rules.

If someone is somehow offended by this, or feel abused, they can follow the steps described in the answers to [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users) and ask moderators to reset the location field, but the moderators might as well decline the flag.

Bottom line: it can be used, but has no real value.

Comment: Yeah. Nobody really cares what's in your profile, so long as it's not disruptive to the site or violates the be nice policy. Emojis are w/e.

Comment: There are people that care, but as said in my answer too: you are free to express yourself in your user profile @Emrakul

Comment: @PatrickHofman I guess the better way of saying it is, it's SE policy to not care. But yeah.

Comment: Then we agree @Emrakul

Comment: Here we are, now we have two opinions, one NO  and one it's ok  so who can we follow ?

Comment: @L.Y  whatever you wish. Free will. :)

Comment: The consensus is the same: SE doesn't prescribe strict rules on the user profile, except abusive or offensive stuff, so actually we both say the same, however I say I personally wouldn't like to see them @L.Y

Answer (score -2):

Please don't. This is a sad place without [fun](/questions/tagged/fun). We hate emojis. No, seriously. Why would you use emojis anywhere? They distract from the purpose of the site. They are considered *fluff* in posts and comments too.

Your user profile gives space on expressing yourself, judging the colored and animated *about me* sections, so probably you can get away with it, personally I wouldn't like to see them anywhere. The policy however isn't that strict.

Comment: Yes @Patrick Hofman i'm with you, but if you set the Emoji in your Name profile it show you an error message, but in Local it not, so i think the developer need to check the name of Location like the Display name, i'm wrong?

Comment: They could and I think they should. But should they ban *Outer space* and other similar locations too? Where is the line?

Comment: mmm, we are here to help so we can help them ;)

Comment: remove the zalgo/upside down text/ **user names** and I can consider this one....

Comment: @Derpy Indeed. That one is even worse. There is a bunch of this kind of unwanted user experience.

Comment: ... imho, standard Lewis quote still applies: *"When I was ten, I read fairy tales in secret and would have been ashamed if I had been found doing so. Now that I am fifty I read them openly. When I became a man I put away childish things, including the fear of childishness and the desire to be very grown up."*

Comment: You are free to do so as I said, but I wouldn't like them. @Derpy